# odoo cant confirm orders by email

Tags: python, odoo-8

I do have a new odoo 8 installation on a synology rackstation and experience trouble sending some email: e.g. confirm a sales order to the client.

Odoo Configuration: Odoo-8, Webstation on

- Sending an email from the Odoo admin -> email - email is OK
- Odoo is sending an automated "system notification" confirming a sales order: Document Model: sale.order, OK
- Printing a sales order- ok, however warning wkhtmltopdf is missing
- Confirming a sales order by email- Not Good -> Error

  OpenERP Server Error

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 499, in _handle_exception
      return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 516, in dispatch
      result = self._call_function(**self.params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 282, in _call_function
      return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
      return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 279, in checked_call
      return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 732, in __call__
      return self.method(*args, **kw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/http.py", line 375, in response_wrap
      response = f(*args, **kw)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
      return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
      return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 54, in default_get
      res.get('model'), res.get('res_id'), context=context
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 103, in onchange_template_id
      values = self.generate_email_for_composer_batch(cr, uid, template_id, [res_id], context=context)[res_id]
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py", line 167, in generate_email_for_composer_batch
      template_values = self.pool.get('email.template').generate_email_batch(cr, uid, template_id, res_ids, fields=fields, context=ctx)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/email_template/email_template.py", line 514, in generate_email_batch
      result, format = self.pool['report'].get_pdf(cr, uid, [res_id], report_service, context=ctx), 'pdf'
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/report/models/report.py", line 252, in get_pdf
      paperformat, specific_paperformat_args, save_in_attachment
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
      return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/var/packages/Odoo8/target/addons/report/models/report.py", line 416, in _run_wkhtmltopdf
      process = subprocess.Popen(wkhtmltopdf, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
      errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  ```

I am not certain if the trouble is just the missing subprocess.Popen(wkhtmltopdf ...or a script error at line 710 or 1335?

I have not downloaded the script but may be somebody know the subprocess.py as I have no python experience.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is partly written in German. Further, most of the English text is really hard to understand. Could you please try to re-phrase your question to make clear how the problem occurred and what you have tried to solve it?

Comment: sorry, it has been updated...